# :onclick doesn't work in button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, onclick

im trying to call a function through onclick method of a button. here is the code:

```
      <%= button_to "Close" , :onclick => "show_back(), return false" %>
```

but it doesn't work, everytime i click the button an error occours

" No action responded to 29. Actions: checkout, create, destroy, edit, find_cart, index, new, save_order, show, and update "

how ever when i impliment the same thing in a href it works

```
     <a onclick="show_back();return false;" href="#."> Close </a>
```

can anyone plz tell me what im doing wrong, thanks in advance..

Answer (score 5):

you can try this

```
=link_to "value", "javascript:function()"
```

and add your class, if you use like bootstrap, you can try:

```
=link_to "value", "javascript:function()", class: 'btn btn-default'
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar. My problem was that I wanted to fire an addCookie() function when a user click logged in.

Did that with:

```
<%= submit_tag 'Go', class: "ses_submit_btn", :onclick => "addCookie()" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. the key was realizing that it has to be the html_options hash

```
<%= button_to "Click", designer_path(@current_user), { :onclick => "debugger", :class=>"button", :method => :put }  %>
```