# What is the equivalent of HTML'S input tag in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-helpers

I want to be able to generate this

```
<input id="address" type="textarea" value="Write your Address here.">
```

Using some ruby form helpers.

***Any hints ?***

Comment: Input types would be either `type='text'` or a `<textarea>` tag. There isn't an `<input type='textbox'>`. Which do you want?

Comment: And is it bound to a field in your model?

Comment: [Appropriate docs are here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-text_area)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you meant `textarea` since there is no such thing as `textbox`.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_area_tag

if it's not tied to a field in your model

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_area

if it is.

Comment: Thanks! that was it , how about `<input type="button" value="Encode" onclick="codeAddress()">` in which I'll be firing that method called codeAddress?

Comment: `button_to` or `button_tag` should work just fine, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5441518/onclick-doesnt-work-in-button-to